# How to add check mark on an image after submission click

Tags: html

I am trying to set up a website with a different kind of sign up style. I want an image to be clickable and a check mark to appear at the top right of the image when clicked.

When I click the image nothing actually is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick property in the image tag and call a jQuery function, in which you can then make the check mark visible. You can refer to this website for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp